Is every quantum channel covariant with respect to some non-trivial Hamiltonian?
When asking whether every channel is covariant with respect to some non-trivial unitary channel I mean the following:

Does there for every CPTP map $\Phi:\mathbb C^{n\times n}\to\mathbb C^{n\times n}$ exist a unitary $U\in\mathbb C^{n\times n}$ such that $U\neq e^{i\phi}{\bf1}$ for any $\phi\in\mathbb R$ and $\Phi(U\rho U^\dagger)=U\Phi(\rho)U^\dagger$ for all $\rho$?

As the exponential map, of course, provides a one-to-one relation between non-trivial unitaries and non-trivial Hamiltonians ($H\neq E\cdot{\bf1}$ for any $E\in\mathbb R$) it is neither surprising nor difficult to see that the above question is equivalent to:

Does there for every CPTP map $\Phi:\mathbb C^{n\times n}\to\mathbb C^{n\times n}$ exist $H\in\mathbb C^{n\times n}$ Hermitian such that $H\neq E\cdot{\bf1}$ for any $E\in\mathbb R$ and $\Phi([H,\rho])=[H,\Phi(\rho)]$ for all $\rho$?

To give some context: covariance is central, e.g., to quantum thermodynamics as it encodes time-translation symmetry $\Phi(e^{-itH}\rho e^{itH})=e^{-itH}\Phi(\rho)e^{itH}$. From this perspective the above question asks about whether every quantum channel is symmetric with respect to some non-trivial closed-system evolution.

(This is a Q&A style question meant as a contribution to the list of counterexamples in quantum information)

This quesiton passes all of Norbert Schuch's canonical channel examples except for the last one: consider the entanglement breaking channel
$$
\Phi(\rho):={\rm tr}(F\rho)\sigma_1+{\rm tr}(({\bf1}-F)\rho)\sigma_2
$$
with $F=|0\rangle\langle 0|=\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2=|+\rangle\langle +|$. Its Pauli transfer matrix reads
$$
\mathcal P(\Phi)=\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2}
\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
To see that this is a counterexample to our problem we have to show that if any $H\in\mathbb C^{2\times 2}$ Hermitian satisfies $\Phi([H,\cdot])=[H,\Phi(\cdot)]$, then $H$ has to be a multiple of the identity. Starting from
$$
H=\begin{pmatrix}h_{11}&h_{12}\\h_{12}^*&h_{22}\end{pmatrix}
$$
one readily computes
$$
\mathcal P([H,\cdot])=\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -i (h_{11}-h_{22}) & -2 i\, {\rm Im}\, h_{12} \\
 0 & i (h_{11}-h_{22}) & 0 & -2 i\, {\rm Re}\,h_{12} \\
 0 & 2 i\, {\rm Im}\,h_{12} & 2 i\, {\rm Re}\,h_{12} & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and thus
\begin{align*}
0&=\mathcal P(0)\\
&=\mathcal P\big( \Phi\circ[H,\cdot]-[H,\cdot]\circ \Phi \big)\\
&=\mathcal P(\Phi)\mathcal P([H,\cdot])-\mathcal P([H,\cdot])\mathcal P(\Phi)\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
i \,{\rm Im}\,h_{12} & -i \,{\rm Im}\,h_{12} & -i \,{\rm Re}\,h_{12} & i \,{\rm Im}\,h_{12} \\
 i \,{\rm Re}\,h_{12}-\frac{i}{2}  (h_{11}-h_{22}) & 0 & 0 & \frac{i}{2}  (h_{11}-h_{22})+i \,{\rm Re}\,h_{12} \\
 -i\, {\rm Im}\,h_{12} & i\, {\rm Im}\,h_{12} & i\, {\rm Re}\,h_{12} & i\, {\rm Im}\,h_{12}
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}
But this is only possible ${\rm Re}\,h_{12}=0={\rm Im}\,h_{12}$ and, subsequently, $\frac{i}{2}  (h_{11}-h_{22})=0$, i.e. $h_{11}=h_{22}=:E\in\mathbb R$ meaning $H=E\cdot{\bf1}$, as desired.
Alternatively, one may consider a Pauli diagonal channel $\Phi$—that is, there exist $a,b,c\in\mathbb R$ such that
$
\mathcal P(\Phi)={\rm diag}(1,a,b,c)
$—in which case
\begin{align*}
\mathcal P\big( &\Phi\circ[H,\cdot]-[H,\cdot]\circ \Phi \big)\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -i (a-b) (h_{11}-h_{22}) & -2 i (a-c) \,{\rm Im}\,h_{12} \\
 0 & -i (a-b) (h_{11}-h_{22}) & 0 & -2 i (b-c) \,{\rm Re}\,h_{12} \\
 0 & -2 i (a-c) \,{\rm Im}\,h_{12} & -2 i (b-c) \,{\rm Re}\,h_{12} & 0 
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}
Hence if $a,b,c$ are pairwise distinct, then (and only then) is $\Phi$ not covariant with respect to any non-trivial Hamiltonian. E.g., $\mathcal P(\Phi)={\rm diag}(1,2/3,1/3,0)$ would be another counterexample to our conjecture, and even a unital one at that.
